# Change type on bool value in template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

I'm learning template step by step, and I think this is the last thing that I need to do for my current project:

```
template < typename Object, bool Shared>
class  Foo {

  private:
    struct SubFoo {

      //if Shared == true -> FooShared  foo;
      //if Shared == false -> FooBasic  foo;
      ???          foo;
      Object       data;
    };
};
```

I know that won't work as easily than `MagicType foo;` so don't worry about modify the code.
I have no C++ limitation (g++6.2, I wonder how get g++7) so even concepts are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) template in [`#include <type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits):

```
typename std::conditional<Shared, FooShared, FooBasic>::type foo;
```

As noted in the comment, c++14 included an easier to use variation called `std::conditional_t` as an alias:

```
std::conditional_t<Shared, FooShared, FooBasic> foo;
```

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct FooShared
{
    FooShared() { std::cout << "FooShared\n"; }
};

struct FooBasic
{
    FooBasic() { std::cout << "FooBasic\n"; }
};

template <bool shared>
class foo
{
    //typename std::conditional<shared, FooShared, FooBasic>::type mytype;
    std::conditional_t<shared, FooShared, FooBasic> mytype;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    foo<true> a;
    foo<false> b;
}
```

Comment: Oh nice one, do you know if there is something like that with concepts by any chance?

Comment: Yes - removed. I copied and amended from another piece of code.

Comment: `std::conditional_t` makes this slightly easier to use in C++14.